# Inserting data into associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class property where i define an associative array

```
private $jsonArray = array('Friends' => array());
```

Im trying to have the array have each friend be put into the array Friends 
[Accepted] = test

```
 $query = "SELECT Username, Status 
          FROM Users 
          INNER JOIN Friends 
          ON Users.idUser = Friends.idFriend 
          WHERE Friends.idUser = ? ";

    // Prepares and excutes the query
    if($stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query))
    {

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($friend, $status); 

        for ($i=0; $stmt->fetch(); $i++) 
        { 

           $this->jsonArray['Friends'][$status] = $friend;
        } 

    }
```

Is this the correct way to define the key for the friend it works but when i json encode its a dict and no longer an array

```
{
    "response": {
        "status":"Success",
        "friends": [
            "Andrew",
            "Jake",
            "Matt",
            "Phil",
            "Colton"
        ],
        "groups": [
            {
                "GroupId": "12",
                "GroupMembers": [
                    "Andrew",
                    "Matt",
                    "Colton"
                ],
                "GroupName": “Group1”
            },
            {
                "GroupId": "12",
                "GroupMembers": [
                    "Phil",
                    "Matt",
                    "Colton"
                ],
                "GroupName": "Room 201"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this you'll always have one `$friend` per `[$status]` - if that is wanted, then it's ok. But from the looks, you'd be better off with something like this

```
for ($i=0; $stmt->fetch(); $i++)  {
    $this->jsonArray['Friends'][$status][] = $friend;
}
```

Now you'll have an array of `$friend`s inside `[$status]`.

```
...
Friends: {
    "Accepted": ["friend1", "friend2", ...]
}
...
```

---

Or this

```
for ($i=0; $stmt->fetch(); $i++)  {
    $this->jsonArray['Friends'][] = $friend;
}
```

Since you know their `$status` - why even use it?

```
...
Friends: ["friend1", "friend2", ...]
...
```

Comment: that would give an array of Accepted

Comment: the status the key of each user within the Friends array

Comment: But aren't they all `Accepted`?

Comment: Can you post the JSON schema you want (in your original question)?

Comment: @user2872510 I think what @kingkero is getting at is that your sql query is ONLY fetching friends with accepted status, therefore the `accepted` status key is redundant. It's only useful if you're getting all friends in any state.